# BXSlider, how can I change CSS or color of a DIV depending on slide visible

Tags: php, jquery, bxslider

I have a bxslider thats pretty standard, v4.0. I have the CSS creating the full screen effect in the background, and a large DIV on top. I want the DIV backgeround color to change with each slide, to color match the slide photo.

[See Example](http://adamepp.com/dev/toolbox/Untitled-1.html)
Is there a way to do this in the function?

Current function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        auto:true,
        pager:false,
        nextSelector: '#bx-next',
        prevSelector: '#bx-prev',
        nextText: '<img src="btn_slider_next.png" />',
        prevText: '<img src="btn_slider_prev.png" />',
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the div stationary or do you have 1 slide -> 1 div set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BXSlider has some very extensive and well documented callback options that you can use when you instantiate the slider:

http://bxslider.com/options#onSliderLoad

You'll probably want onSlideAfter, so when you create the slider, it'll look like

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    ...
    onSlideAfter: function (elem) { ... YOUR CODE HERE ... }
});
```

In order to change the color within that function, you could include the hex code you want associated with each image in an HTML5 data attribute.

```
<img src="img1.jpg" data-color="#ff0000" />
```

Then use the first argument passed to BX's onSlideAfter (which is the jQuery element for the current slide) to get that color and apply it to the background.

```
function (elem) {
    $('#background-div').css('background-color', elem.data('color'));
}
```